# Mui-DataTables custom sort with customBodyRender

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am using Mui-DataTables in React TS.

I have a customBodyRender column that display's a checkbox in the cell. I also want to sort the data based on the value. The underlying data is boolean.
Below is the code I am trying.
It is not working, please help me out here.

P.S I cannot use the Mui-DataTables's native row selection option, since I also need to use the filter and search while row selected.

```
const defaultColumns = [
{
  name: "_id",
  label: "ID",
  options: {
    display: false,
    filter: true,
  },
},
{
  name: "selected",
  label: "Selected",
  options: {
    display: true,
    filter: true,
    sort: true,
    customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
      return <Checkbox onChange={(e) => MapSelection(tableMeta, e.target.checked)} checked={value} />;
    },
    sortCompare: (order) => {
      return (obj1, obj2) => {
        console.log(order,obj1,obj2);
        return ((obj1.data === obj1.data)? 0 : obj1.data? -1 : 1) * (order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
      };
    }
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You compared only obj1

```
      return (obj1, obj2) => {
        console.log(order,obj1,obj2);
        return ((obj1.data === obj1.data)? 0 : obj1.data? -1 : 1) * (order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
      };
    }
```

Solution is

```
      return (obj1, obj2) => {
        console.log(order,obj1,obj2);
        return ((obj1.data === obj2.data)? 0 : obj1.data? -1 : 1) * (order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
      };
    }
```